# Do not allow the value to go to =< 0 in input

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code that let the user press the minus and reach values like 0, -1, -2, ... -999...:

http://jsfiddle.net/yrn58egv/

**HTML**

```
<table class="table table-condensed table-hover table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="shrink">TICKET</th>
            <th class="shrink">VALUE</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Y00001</td>
            <td>
                <div class="input-group">   <span class="input-group-btn">
                        <button class="btn btn-default btn-minuse" type="button">-</button>
                    </span>

                    <input type="text" name="Y00001" class="form-control text-center" maxlength="3" value="">   <span class="input-group-btn">
                        <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">+</button>
                    </span>

                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Y00002</td>
            <td>
                <div class="input-group">   <span class="input-group-btn">
                        <button class="btn btn-default btn-minuse" type="button">-</button>
                    </span>

                    <input type="text" name="Y00002" class="form-control text-center" maxlength="3" value="">   <span class="input-group-btn">
                        <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">+</button>
                    </span>

                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Y07851</td>
            <td>
                <div class="input-group">   <span class="input-group-btn">
                        <button class="btn btn-default btn-minuse" type="button">-</button>
                    </span>

                    <input type="text" name="Y07851" class="form-control text-center" maxlength="3" value="">   <span class="input-group-btn">
                        <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">+</button>
                    </span>

                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Y71710</td>
            <td>
                <div class="input-group">   <span class="input-group-btn">
                        <button class="btn btn-default btn-minuse" type="button">-</button>
                    </span>

                    <input type="text" name="Y71710" class="form-control text-center" maxlength="3" value="">   <span class="input-group-btn">
                        <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">+</button>
                    </span>

                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
$('.btn').on('click', function() {
  var $input = $(this).closest('.input-group').find('input');
  var val = +$input.val();
  $input.val(($(this).hasClass('btn-minuse') ? val - 1 : val + 1) || 0);
});
```

How can the input do not let the value go to =< 0? So if there is nothing in the input and press minus or plus, the value will be 1. If 1 and press minus, it should keep the 1.

Comment: What is `btn-minuse`? And do you not want value <=0 ever?

Comment: Answer updated with full code. Yes, do not want value <= 0 ever. I am not worried if the user type it... I am just worried about the button minus not letting the user reach <= 0

Comment: `<input type=number min=0>` should work.

Comment: @Khrys I updated my answer to handle both cases (type and click)

Comment: Check the answer exactly the way you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('.btn').on('click', function() {
  var $input = $(this).closest('.input-group').find('input');
  var val = +$input.val();
  val = ($(this).hasClass('btn-minuse') ? val - 1 : val + 1) || 0;
  $input.val((val < 0 ? val + 1 : val)) 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is check if the value is 0 or below before you set the input's value field.

```
$('.btn').on('click', function() {
  var $input = $(this).closest('.input-group').find('input');
  var val = +$input.val();
  var newVal = $(this).hasClass('btn-minuse') ? val - 1 : val + 1;
  $input.val(newVal <= 0 ? 0 : newVal);
});
```

In the above code, I set the value that you were passing to the function to a new variable, newVal, and then checked that variable before calling the function.  Your "|| 0" code was not going to do anything as that was just ORing to see if the previous part had returned a value.

A JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bdb4dnpp/

Answer (score 0):

You need to write the code to do what you wrote in English.  For example:

```
var newval = ($(this).hasClass('btn-minuse') ? val - 1 : val + 1)
if (newval < 0)
    { newval = 1; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
$input.val(($(this).hasClass('btn-minuse') ? val - 1 : val + 1) || 0);
```

to

```
$input.val(($(this).hasClass('btn-minuse') ? (val - 1 > 0? val - 1: 1) : val + 1);
```

To make sure that the user can't type in a negative value, add a `no-neg` class to all inputs

```
<input type="text" name="Y00001" class="no-neg" ...
```

and add

```
(".no-neg").change(function() {
    var current = parseInt(this.value, 10);
    this.value = current > 0? current: 1;
});
```

Updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xx4prcqj/).

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.btn').on('click', function() {    
   var $input = $(this).closest('.input-group').find('input');
   var val = +$input.val();

   // add this section 
   if(val <= 0){
       $input.val('1');
       return;
   }

   $input.val(($(this).hasClass('btn-minuse') ? val - 1 : val + 1) || 0);      
});
```